# integrating index.html with search with searchkick in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

new to rails here. I have my normal index page for a User controller below.

I just added search to my app with search kick and elastic search.

How would I merge the two separate blocks of code to work together in one view (index.html.erb)? I'm using a _user partial for the final render.

Currently I'm getting this error because they aren't integrated correctly.

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#index
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

<div class="container-fluid">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= render user %>
    </div>
```

views/user/index.html.erb

Search Block

```
 <div class="books-search">
      <h1>Search Books</h1>
      <%= form_tag users_path, method: :get do %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: 'form-control' %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Normal Index Block

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= render user %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate %>
```

User Controller

```
def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @user = User.search(params[:query])
    else
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a search param your controller will do:

```
@user = User.search(params[:query])
```

while view expects to have `@users` variable, not `@user`. `@users` is nil.

Comment: ok so i fixed the controller. still getting the same error. my biggest focus is trying to combine those two blocks in the view into one.

Comment: @rs_19   why you are using different instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @users = User.search(params[:query]), page: params[:page], per_page: 10
    else
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
end
```

then in your view(index.html.erb)

use this @users instance variable to loop over each user